# How to load an entire webpage with the jquery .html method?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have included a jquery script in my webpage that by clicking on a bar, the bar expands and loads HTML content via the jquery .html method.
[expandable jquery window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzVaG.png)

```css
#processmap {
 height: 20px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 20px;
 right: 20px;
    font-size: .8em;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #EF7100;
 box-shadow: 0px 11px 5px -10px rgba(153,153,153,1);
 border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 z-index: 999;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Please ensure that no elements, particularly pictures, exceed 480 px width. -->
<html>
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#processmap").click(function() {
     if ($(this).height() > 20) {
      $(this).animate({
       height: "20px"
      }, 300, 'swing', function() {
       $(this).html("Open Business Process Map");
      });
     } else {
      var content = 'Close this window.</br><iframe style="top: 20px; height:100%; width: 100%; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden" src="processmap_project.html"></iframe>'
      $(this).animate({
       height: "150px" 
      }, 300, 'swing', function() {
      $(this).html(content);
      });
     }
    });
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="processmap">
   Open Business Process Map
  </div>
  <iframe id="art" style="height:100%; width:100%; align:top; border:none; overflow:scroll" src="https://***"></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Via this method, I would like to load an entire iFrame into the expanded window. However, I figured that formatting the iframe within the JavaScript code is not working well. (Paddings and margins are not picked up.)

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#processmap").click(function() {
   if ($(this).height() > 20) {
    $(this).animate({
     height: "20px"
    }, 300, 'swing', function() {
     $(this).html("Open Business Process Map");
    });
   } else {
    var content = 'processmap_shell.html'
    $(this).animate({
     height: "150px" 
    }, 300, 'swing', function() {
    $(this).html(content);
    });
   }
  });
 });
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Please ensure that no elements, particularly pictures, exceed 480 px width. -->
<html>
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  Close this window.</br>
  <iframe id="process" src="processmap_project.html"></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Palpably, $(this).html('processmap_shell.html') does not work. Would you know how could I load the page processmap_shell.html in the window instead and thus, refer to the main.css more easily?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the html code by `.load()`.

```
$(this).load('file.html');
```

Comment: This is probably the most effective method.